# Can one say kiddush levana by day?

Tags: halacha, kiddush-levanah, daytime

Can someone say "[kiddush levana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiddush_levana)" by day if he sees the moon clearly, in full? Or is there a reason why we only say it in the evening other than the fact that the day starts at night.

Comment: You can't see a full moon during the day...

Comment: I just did....(mostly full)--if it was fully full it would be past the 15th anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The Rama rules that one can only recite Kiddush Levana "at night when the moon is shining and we benefit from its light" ([OC 426:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2140)).

Comment: http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/34_15_74.pdf

Comment: I just note the vast majority of rishonim did not agree with this.

Comment: Does this mean one should wait until Tzet ha-kochavim, or is it enough to wait until sunset?